# A single map load is charged for each instantiation of a Google map or panorama object in an Android

Tags: android, dictionary

A single map load is charged for each instantiation of a Google map or panorama object in an Android. A GMSMapView or GMSPanoramaView object on iOS.
    One of MapFragment, SupportMapFragment, MapView, StreetViewPanoramaFragment, SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment, or StreetViewPanoramaView on Android. A map load is counted each time the related onCreate() method is called.
 I just want to see if we have created the oncreate for one map activity and creted the map now next time when the same map activit is launched again, can we reuse the last map object

Comment: I'm not trying to mock you but I didn't understand anything.

Comment: what i want exactly is that the map obejct once created should be reused and not created again and again...because when the onCreate of support manager gets called i feel its a new instance. that i need to avoid

Comment: Which class do you want to make singleton?

Comment: i dont want to make any class singleton...